# I want to run on Alexa's custom skills on a fixed basis

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am sorry if I am using a translation tool because I am using a translation tool

I'd like Alexa to talk to Alexa on a regular basis with Alexa's custom skills, but how do I do it?

Example: alexa xxx at 6 o'clock

I want to make custom skills that will do every day when I say it

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to design the skill's Interaction Model so that it responds to invocations that involve the invocation word of your skill and a specific intent in one of the [formats specified by Amazon](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/understanding-how-users-invoke-custom-skills.html).

Possibilities for your example:

"Alexa, **ask** *Awesome Skill* **to** set an alarm at 6 o'clock."

"Alexa, set an alarm at 6 o'clock **using** *Awesome Skill*."

---

As far as the functionality after the user schedules something at 6 o'clock, you'll need to look into the [Notifications API](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/alexa-voice-service/notifications-overview.html) and it's limitations.